# DB2 calling stored Procedure in conditional statement

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I need to query a stored procedure and on the basis of result set of that procedure need to make decisions in conditional statement

For instance I have a stored Procedure "Main_SP"

Now if result of "Main_SP" is 'null' then the result should be 'Tweety', but if th result set is not null then result set should be retrieved,

how to do it?

I tried following and some other but none worked.

```
SELECT  
  case Main_SP('MyVariable') 
     when 'null' 
        then 'Tweety' end      
  FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 WITH UR

SELECT  
   case Main_SP('MyVariable') 
     when null 
       then 'Tweety' end      
    FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 WITH UR
```

It is failing the condition, In first command when even it is 'null' it is not printing 'Tweety'.

and while using second, Getting error that 'Null' is not valid in the context.

Comment: ...well, which do you have, `'null'` or `NULL`?  The first is a string (containing the lower-case word 'null`), and the second is the absence of any value whatsoever.  You can compare strings in the `WHEN` like that (or with equals), but nulls have to be compared via `IS NULL`/`IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Is `Main_SP` a stored procedure or a UDF?

Comment: @IanBjorhovde Stored procedure in db2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can use a stored procedure that way.

A stored procedure can return data in two ways

1. As a result set
2. in an output or input/output parm

You're not using option 2 and I don't think a result set is ever NULL.  There might be no records, but the RS itself isn't NULL.  In addition, from what I can see in the manuals, processing a RS from a stored proc inside another stored proc in DB2 requires you to declare an allocate **result set locators**.  But I've never done this.

If your procedure returns a single value or null, you'd be better served by defining it as a function with a return value.  Then your code would be simply:

```
SELECT  
  COALESCE(Main_Fnc('MyVariable'),'Tweety')
FROM 
     SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 WITH UR
```

Comment: I used 'null' just as an example , I meant to ask that this comparison not returns desired result on the basis of those results, I need to use select queries within that conditional statement.... BTW That Store Procedure actually returns String 'null' in case there is no data value.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a stored procedure as part of an SQL fullselect; you would need to have the client that calls the stored procedure handle this logic.  If you must do it on the server, implement a new stored procedure that calls `Main_SP` itself and contains your logic to interpret the result.